# Iterate Cell Statistics Every 5 Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, iterator

[image: There are 2000 rasters inside the FOLDER/WORKSPACE]

If I am going to use cellstat alone, CellStat would produce mean of 2000 rasters inside the FOLDER(ALL RASTERS). I want to average only every 5 raster which would result to 400 rasters.

How do you do this in ArcGIS 10.1?

Comment: How are the rasters named?

Comment: Inside the Folder? M1...M2000.tif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask would be very difficult to do in ModelBuilder, there are not the tools that can create groups of data in that manner. You are hitting the limitations of ModelBuilder.  This can however be done with a few lines of python as shown below.

```py
import arcpy
folder = r"c:\temp"
outfolder = r"C:\tempout"
aL = []
for i in range(1,21): # for 1 to 20
    # create full name and append to list
    fullpath = folder + "\\M" + str(i) + ".tif"
    aL.append(fullpath)

    # When list hits contents of 5 do the analysis and then reset list
    if len(aL) == 5:
        print aL
        outCellStats = arcpy.sa.CellStatistics(aL,"MEAN")
        outpath = outfolder + "\\Mean_" + str(i) + ".tif"
        outCellStats.save(outpath)
        aL = [] # Reset list
```

Comment: What does it mean by range (1,21):?

Comment: _# for 1 to 20..._ I obvious don't have your data so to test the code I'm using less

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it today.  Many people ask the same question so we thank you for your time helping us.

Comment: I confirm that this code solved my problem. Just small detail though, in outpath = outfolder + "\\Mean_" + str(i) + ".tif", the file saves as and starts at Mean_3.tif?

Comment: The output name is built from the current 'i' value which is always the end group value so in my example code the files would be named as: Mean_5.tif, Mean_10.tif, Mean_15.tif, Mean_20.tif. Thus Mean_15.tif would be the mean of the inputs: m11, m12, m13, m14, m15. You can save the output what ever you like, this was just a convenient method.

Comment: Thank you. I renamed the files in different platform. I do not know how to send PMs here, if there is  one, but given how helpful you have been, can you help me in my another question in looping rasters?

Comment: New questions should be asked as new questions not tagged on to the end of an existing question. It's how GIS SE is run. It allow others to find your question and hopefully see the solution. So start a new question, no problem in linking to this Q&A but all questions should stand alone. Also you might get several solutions, which is always useful.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. This is the link to the question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276422/q-looping-for-ndvi-in-different-file-paths-using-r?noredirect=1#comment440401_276422