# Looping for NDVI in different file paths using R?

Tags: r, ndvi, loop

I have different bands separated in different file directory.

I used Raster Calculator to calculate NDVI using "NIR1.tif"-"RED1.tif"/"NIR1.tif"+"RED1.tif" as formula.

The link below describes a loop for StackBand which I supposed is a file containing different bands. In my case, I have separate file path for NIR and RED.

Data is named NIR1...NIR2000.tif and RED1...RED2000.tif.

[Using Loop for calculating NDVI in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163545/using-loop-for-calculating-ndvi)

I prefer using R but I am having difficulties in calling NIR and RED and putting them in a loop to calculate NDVI.

Below is my code:

```
library(raster) 
library(rgdal) 
NDVI< list.files("C:\\Users\\path\\Desktop\\PET\\sample\\", pattern="*.tif", all.files=F, full.names = FALSE, recursive = TRUE, ignore.case = FALSE) 
for (i in 1:length(NDVI)) 
NDVI <- raster(function(x,y) 
(x="NIR"+str(i)+".tif"), (y="red"+str(i)+".tif"), (x-y/x+y) 
writeRaster(NDVI,"NDVI", format="GTiff")
```

I tried to make some revisions in the code.

Comment: Please edit that code out of the comment where it is unformatted into your question where it will look better. The code currently in the question is trying to compute using the file**names**!

Comment: I already edited it. Still, it is not working.

I am having difficulties in iterating the NIR and RED from 1 to 26 in the folder.

Comment: You should also show us the error messages or describe what is happening, or what is not happening.

Comment: Error in .getGDALtransient(x, filename = filename, options = options,  : 
  filename exists; use overwrite=TRUE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your formula is not right. You can't use `(x-y/x+y)`... Is the same than `x - (y/x) + y`. So correct this first.

I'll create some example data:

```r
library(raster)

r <- raster()

userpath <- '/some/path/'

for (i in 1:2000) {
  temp <- setValues(r,sample(x = 0:1000, size = ncell(r), replace = T))
  writeRaster(temp, paste0(userpath,'NIR',i,'.tif'))
  temp <- setValues(r,sample(x = 0:1000, size = ncell(r), replace = T))
  writeRaster(temp, paste0(userpath,'RED',i,'.tif'))
}
```

Read NIR and RED in different objects:

```r
NIR <- list.files(path = userpath, pattern = 'NIR*.*.tif',full.names = T)
RED <- list.files(path = userpath, pattern = 'RED*.*.tif', full.names = T)
```

Maybe, depend of rasters name, raster aren't in order when you use `list.files()`. In my case is something like:

```r
NIR1.tif
NIR10.tif
NIR100.tif
NIR1000.tif
NIR1001.tif
```

You should extract the index from raster name to prevent undesired results:

```r
i2 <- gsub(pattern = '.*NIR',replacement = '',x = NIR)
i2 <- gsub(pattern = '.tif$',replacement = '',x = i2)
i2 <- as.numeric(i2)
```

And finally, compute NDVI inside a loop and save rasters:

```r
for (i in i2) {
  ndvitemp <- overlay(raster(NIR[i]),raster(RED[i]), fun = function(x,y) (x - y)/(x + y))
  writeRaster(ndvitemp, paste0(userpath,'NDVI',i,'.tif'))
}
```

Comment: + writeRaster(temp, paste0(userpath,'red',i,'.tif')) + } 

Error in .getGDALtransient(x, filename = filename, options = options, : filename exists; use overwrite=TRUE There is an error showing after the first writeRaster

Comment: It’s because there is a file with the name that you want to use. Change the name or add `overwrite = T`

Comment: I added overwrite=T after 

  writeRaster(temp, paste0(userpath,'RED',i,'.tif'), overwrite=T)
} but it is still not working

Comment: Can I send you the files and see what you can do with it?

Comment: Hi, Mr. Aldo:

I made some revisions in the code by removing Lines 4-9 and substituting for (i in 1:26) in for (i in seq_along((NIR)). It worked when I did manual calculation, the values are the same. 

Thank you very much and please continue extending your help to us beginners.

Comment: Hi, Mr. Aldo, I want to go back to the code.

When I validate NDVI1.tif with manual calculation, the output values are similar but when I move from NDVI2.tif forward, the values are not the same. I am wondering why?

I checked the name order, it seems okay. So maybe, I am guessing there must be something to be included in the code? @aldo_tapia

Comment: I miss something. Change `seq_along()` with `i2` (I edited the post)

Comment: I figure it out. I added zero padding before NDVI1.tif to make it NDVI0001.tif.